# Swiftdata not refreshing

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I implemented swiftdata to my code and now the list is not refreshing after adding an item. Before implementing swiftdata it worked.

Thats the model:

```
@Model
class Einkauf {
    let name: String
    var anzahl: Int
    
    init(name: String, anzahl: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.anzahl = anzahl
    }
}
```

Thats the ViewModel with the func:

```
class EinkaufViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //@Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    
    //Before SwiftData there was @Published and it worked.
    @Query var items: [Einkauf] = [
        Einkauf(name: "Apfel", anzahl: 1),
        Einkauf(name: "Fanta", anzahl: 10)
    ]
    
    func addItem(context: ModelContext) {
        let newItem = Einkauf(name: "Neuer Artikel", anzahl: 0)
        context.insert(newItem)
        //items.append(newItem)
    }
}
```

Thats the View:

```
struct EinkaufslisteDetailView: View {
    
    @Environment (\.modelContext) var context
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: EinkaufViewModel
    @State private var isDone: Bool = false
    @State private var anzahl: Int = 5
    @State private var textFieldText: String = ""
    
    let kategorieName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
                    List {
                       ForEach(vm.items) { item in
                            EinkaufItemRowView(name: item.name, anzahl: item.anzahl, isDone: isDone, textFieldText: textFieldText)
                            .padding(.vertical)
                        }
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: { vm.addItem(context: context) },
                                    label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                })
                /*.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    EinkaufAddView(vm: vm)
                        .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.7)])
                }*/
            )
            .navigationTitle(kategorieName)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EinkaufslisteDetailView(vm: EinkaufViewModel(), kategorieName: "Testname")
}

struct EinkaufItemRowView: View {
    
    @State var name: String
    @State var anzahl: Int
    @State var isDone: Bool
    @State var textFieldText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: isDone ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "checkmark.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundStyle(isDone ? .green : .primary)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isDone.toggle()
                }
            
            TextField(name, text: $textFieldText)
                .strikethrough(isDone ? true : false)
                .font(.title2)
            
            Spacer()
            
                Button(action: {
                    //guard item.anzahl <= 1 else { return }
                    anzahl -= 1
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                })
            
                Button(action: {
                    anzahl += 1
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                })
            
            Text("\(anzahl)")
                .frame(width: 40)
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I am totally wrong but I assume there is a problem at the view where the add Buttons is with the "context:context" passing.

Comment: `@Published` and `@Query` are not equivalent in any way. `Query` is only for a SwiftUI `View` it does not work in a `class`, in iOS 17+ you should limit `ObservableObject` to a `Combine` pipeline. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches

Comment: @lorem ipsum I understand now that the two property wrappers are not working the same way but what’s wrong with my code or what do I have to add? I watched a tutorial and my code is simply the same but I don’t know why..

Comment: Take the `Query` out of the `class`, you cannot give a `Query` initial values either. Look a the link I attached above. Your code does not match the documentation and should not match any tutorials because it is fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: Ahh now I get it. You think it would work if I put the Query in the view and link it with the items array ? Of course I would change it back to @Published… I can’t test it now :(

Comment: No forget about the ViewModel… Query won’t work with it…. ObservableObjects are for Combine you don’t have any Combine code so get rid of it.

Comment: I have more views, the one with the ObservableObject is just a child view

Comment: you can also perform a regular `fetch` if you look at the documentation I posted on the first comment but it doesn't "listen" you will have to run a `fetch` every time you want to see an update. switch to `@Observable` if you insist in using a "ViewModel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftData, the concept is a little different.

## Query and ModelContext

The `@Query` macro works in the view and keeps data in your view in sync with data in your `ModelContext`.

You insert data into the `ModelContext` and your View updates automatically!

Here's a diagram from the book "**SwiftData Mastery in SwiftUI**" that shows the concept:

[image: Observable Object inserts data into model context and view updates.]

## Updated Code

Here is your modified code with the `@Query` in the View:

```
@Model
class Einkauf {
    let name: String
    var anzahl: Int
    
    init(name: String, anzahl: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.anzahl = anzahl
    }
}

@Observable
class EinkaufViewModel {
    func addItem(context: ModelContext) {
        let newItem = Einkauf(name: "Neuer Artikel", anzahl: 0)
        context.insert(newItem)
    }
}

struct EinkaufslisteDetailView: View {
    @Query var items: [Einkauf] // Query on the view
    @Environment (\.modelContext) var context
    @State var vm: EinkaufViewModel
    @State private var isDone: Bool = false
    @State private var anzahl: Int = 5
    @State private var textFieldText: String = ""
    
    let kategorieName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("", systemImage: "plus.circle") {
                    vm.addItem(context: context)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(kategorieName)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EinkaufslisteDetailView(vm: EinkaufViewModel(), kategorieName: "Testname")
        .modelContainer(for: Einkauf.self, inMemory: true)
}
```

## List Updating

[image: Simulator adding items and updating]

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct hierarchy is the view model already, so don't use classes, just do:

```
struct EinkaufView: View {
    
    //@Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    
    //Before SwiftData there was @Published and it worked.
    @Query var items:
```

You can move the `func addItem` to either the model or in an extension on the context.